# I want ask about sum of rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array like this:

```
formTemporary: [50, '', 50, '', 50]
```

and I have an object like this

```
formEntry: {25}
```

and I want to add `formEntry` to the array.

I want the `formTemporary` like this:

```
formTemporary: [50, 25, 50, 25, 50]
```

After the array complete I want to sum the array with `.reduce`. I want to know how to add the value of `formEntry` to `formTemporary`.

Comment: Could you give us more code?. It's `formEntry` a property of your object or it's the object?

Comment: formTemporary: [
      {
        finalAmount: "50",
      },
      {
        finalAmount: "",
      },
      {
        finalAmount: "50",
      },
      {
        finalAmount: "",
      },
      {
        finalAmount: "50",
      },
    ],

and 
   formEntry : {
      amount: "25",
    },

Comment: and i want add the value from formEntry to formTemporary[].finalAmount

Answer (score 0):

```
const formEntry = 25;
let formTemporary = [50, '', 50, '', 50];
formTemporary = formTemporary.map(record => record || formEntry);
console.log(formTemporary);
```